# Trying to install CIF connector with Maven build to AEM

Tags: maven, aem

Trying to install CIF connector with maven when building NOT to AEMaaCS or AMS (so only to local), and tried breaking down the parts of the connector to install because our maven settings do not allow us to build with an `all` content package. Here is what i have so far for the build, and this is in an `app.dependencies` pom.xml.

```
            <id>local-build</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>!env.CM_BUILD</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
                            <artifactId>filevault-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <embeddeds combine.children="append">
                                    <embedded>
                                        <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>cif-connector-graphql</artifactId>
                                        <type>jar</type>
                                        <target>/apps/aem-activate-vendor-packages/application/install</target>
                                    </embedded>
                                    <embedded>
                                        <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>cif-virtual-catalog</artifactId>
                                        <type>jar</type>
                                        <target>/apps/aem-activate-vendor-packages/application/install</target>
                                    </embedded>
                                    <embedded>
                                        <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>graphql-client</artifactId>
                                        <filter>true</filter>
                                    </embedded>
                                    <embedded>
                                        <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>magento-graphql</artifactId>
                                        <filter>true</filter>
                                    </embedded>
                                </embeddeds>
                                <subPackages>
                                    <subPackage>
                                        <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>cif-connector-content</artifactId>
                                        <filter>true</filter>
                                    </subPackage>
                                    <subPackage>
                                        <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>cif-virtual-catalog-content</artifactId>
                                        <filter>true</filter>
                                    </subPackage>
                                </subPackages>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

And here are the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
            <artifactId>cif-connector-graphql</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
            <artifactId>cif-virtual-catalog</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
            <artifactId>cif-connector-content</artifactId>
            <type>zip</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
            <artifactId>cif-virtual-catalog-content</artifactId>
            <type>zip</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-client</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql.client.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.commerce.cif</groupId>
            <artifactId>magento-graphql</artifactId>
            <version>${magento.graphql.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.jackrabbit:filevault-package-maven-plugin:1.1.4:validate-package (default-validate-package) on project aem-activate.app.dependencies: Execution default-validate-package of goal org.apache.jackrabbit:filevault-package-maven-plugin:1.1.4:validate-package failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

Any help with what might be going wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, Jordan! If I understand this correctly, you're trying to install every package and bundle in the connector. Can you share the maven command you use for this and the package?

Comment: Hi Daniel. That is correct! so I am running `mvn clean install -PautoInstallSinglePackage` as the normal build. But with this new profile, I would be adding on a second flag so it would be `mvn clean install -PautoInstallSinglePackage,local-build`

Comment: If you add -Xe, can you get more information regarding the error?